# What strategies can be used to develop a segmentation algorithm to decide whether an individual pixel is blue or red

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am new into image processing and need help in developing my knowledge while developing segmentation algorithm. I need to identify whether pixel is red or blue also pink pixel should be considered as red

Comment: Nobody can possibly help with such a vague question. Please try and improve it with sample image(s), code and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I have to start coding and want to know how can I achieve the result of identifying red or blue pixel considering I have no prequisite knowledge regarding the same.

Comment: You can't write code until you know what you are trying to achieve. We can't help you without seeing your image and understanding what you are trying to do... so please show your image and a separate, marked up image showing what you are looking for.